# MySQL: int field that can only increase

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I'm searching for a way to make the required logic for a numeric field increase on an update.
The case:

1. I have a table with id:int, data:json, version:int fields. A user sent data, and I need to insert it (if the ID is absent) or update it (if the ID is present). I managed to do this in two ways:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, data, version) VALUES (:id, :data, :version) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=:data, version=:version
```

or

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (id, data, version) VALUES (:id, :data, :version)
```

Both options work well. But I need to check that the version isn't outdated (for example, the user sends data to update with version 7, but somebody already updated the data, and the version is already 7 or 8 - in this case, I shouldn't update).
I can divide my queries into a few ones, but don't want to do this and try to manage all in a single request. Possible options I can imagine could be:

1. Set some requirements for the version field that it can only increase when updated.
2. Add somehow `where version < :version` into one of the requests above.
   But I can't find solutions for any of these options. Is this possible at all with a single request?

Comment: Use according trigger which checks that old value is not less or strictly greater than new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try query

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, data, version) 
  VALUES (:id, :data, :version) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    data=case version< :version then :data else data end 
   ,version=case version< :version then :version else version end
;
```

Maybe an extra row update won't hurt.

Comment: thank you, it really works (with small fixes for syntax `data=(case when version< :version then :data else data end) `)